# Selenium, Python, exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException Error message

Tags: python, selenium

I have been following a video on YT how to create a PS5 Stock bot that checks if the product is back in stock, but the last part on sending a notification was not uploaded (Part 3) but thanks to the lessons that I had on team treehouse is enabled to solve that my self until this error showed up and was hoping some could help me.

**How to script runs**

The script runs on https://wayscript.com/ and runs as follow:

`Time Trigger > HTTP Trigger > HTTP Response > Python script > IF > Send message to discord server.`

**Here are the video's I am referring to**

Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rHqekQeIn0&t=248s

Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3YTRvAoa3U

Part 3: Not Published

**About the Error**

The error happens not in the same order most of the time the script runs 2/3 times before the error shows up and the error does also not stay most of the time the error repeats himself 2x and after that, the script run fine for 2 or 3 times and it repeats itself.

**where do I need help with:**

I need help with solving the error.

**Python script:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import csv 
from datetime import date



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0')



browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60)


browser.get('https://www.wehkamp.nl/sony-playstation-5-16644186/')

all_span = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
all_span = [i.text for i in all_span]

date = date.today()
is_beschikbaar = ""

if "uitverkocht" in all_span:
    print("Playstation 5 is niet op voorraad")
    is_beschikbaar = False
else: 
    print("Playstation 5 is weer op voorraad")
    is_beschikbaar = True
    
    
headers = ["date", "is de Playstation 5 Beschikbaar?"]

with open ("ps5_beschikbaarheid.csv", "a" ) as csvfile:
    write = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #write.writerow(headers)
    write.writerow([date, is_beschikbaar])
    
variables['text'] = is_beschikbaar 
    
browser.close()
```

**Error message**

```py
12:19:00    Finished running
12:19:56    Time Trigger ran.
12:19:56    Executing your code
12:19:56    Playstation 5 is niet op voorraad
12:19:56    Executed your code
12:19:56    If statement is false.
12:19:56    Sleep ran.
12:19:56    Finished running


12:21:00    Time Trigger ran.
12:21:00    Executing your code

            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "python_step", line 22, in <module>
                all_span = [i.text for i in all_span]
            File "python_step", line 22, in <listcomp>
                all_span = [i.text for i in all_span]
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 76, in text
                return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
12:21:00          return self._parent.execute(command, params)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
                self.error_handler.check_response(response)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
                raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
            selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
            (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)

12:21:00    SCRIPT TERMINATED: Script haulted due to an error from the python_code module.
12:21:00    Finished running
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to rewrite the both lines:

```
all_span = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
all_span = [i.text for i in all_span]
```

by:

```
all_spans = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
nbrspans = len(all_spans)
all_texts = []
for i in range(nbrspans):
    all_spans = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
    all_texts.append(all_spans[i].text)
```

and after you deal with all_texts

the error means you have to reload the the search of spans